# How to hide or disable "add to campaign" button in Contact page layout ( LEX )

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, button

I tried to remove from contact page layout the "add to campaign" from Search Layouts. But it's still visible

[image]

second step config:

[image]

any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to wait and refresh it again. Sometimes in LEX due to cache it shows old UI. A hard refresh solves this issue.

[image]

[image]